# Restrict results to top N rows per group

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group, ranking

The following query:

```
SELECT
    year, id, rate
FROM h
WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
ORDER BY id, rate DESC
```

yields:

```
year | id  | rate
2006 | p01 |  8.0
2003 | p01 |  7.4
2008 | p01 |  6.8
2001 | p01 |  5.9
2007 | p01 |  5.3
2009 | p01 |  4.4
2002 | p01 |  3.9
2004 | p01 |  3.5
2005 | p01 |  2.1
2000 | p01 |  0.8
2001 | p02 | 12.5
2004 | p02 | 12.4
2002 | p02 | 12.2
2003 | p02 | 10.3
2000 | p02 |  8.7
2006 | p02 |  4.6
2007 | p02 |  3.3
```

I want only the top 5 rows for each id:

```
year | id  | rate
2006 | p01 |  8.0
2003 | p01 |  7.4
2008 | p01 |  6.8
2001 | p01 |  5.9
2007 | p01 |  5.3
2001 | p02 | 12.5
2004 | p02 | 12.4
2002 | p02 | 12.2
2003 | p02 | 10.3
2000 | p02 |  8.7
```

Is there a way to do this using some kind of LIMIT like modifier that applies to each group?

Comment: This can be done in MySQL, but it is not as simple as adding a `LIMIT` clause. Here is an article that explains the problem in detail: [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) It's a good article - he introduces an elegant but naïve solution to the "Top N per group" problem, and then gradually improves on it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT
year, id, rate
FROM h
WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
AND id IN (SELECT rid FROM table2)
GROUP BY id, year
ORDER BY id, rate DESC) LIMIT 5

Comment: This problem has been resolved by introducing sql windowing functions as it is explained in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38854846/2723942

Comment: @danben [new link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122025923/https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Answer (score 171):

You want to find ***top n rows per group***. This answer provides a generic solution using example data that is different from OP.

In MySQL 8 or later you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) function depending on the exact definition of top 5. Below are the numbers generated by these functions based on `value` sorted descending. Notice how ties are handled:

| pkid | catid | value | row_number | rank | dense_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p01 | 100 | *1 | *1 | *1 |
| 2 | p01 | 90 | *2 | *2 | *2 |
| 3 | p01 | 90 | *3 | *2 | *2 |
| 4 | p01 | 80 | *4 | *4 | *3 |
| 5 | p01 | 80 | *5 | *4 | *3 |
| 6 | p01 | 80 | 6 | *4 | *3 |
| 7 | p01 | 70 | 7 | 7 | *4 |
| 8 | p01 | 60 | 8 | 8 | *5 |
| 9 | p01 | 50 | 9 | 9 | 6 |
| 10 | p01 | 40 | 10 | 10 | 7 |

Once you have chosen the function, use it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY catid ORDER BY value DESC) AS n
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE n <= 5
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uibo9f8-)

---

In MySQL 5.x you can use poor man's rank over partition to achieve desired result: outer join the table with itself and for each row, count the number of rows ***before*** it (e.g. the before row could be the one with higher value).

The following will produce results similar to `RANK` function:

```
SELECT t.pkid, t.catid, t.value, COUNT(b.value) + 1 AS rank
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t AS b ON b.catid = t.catid AND b.value > t.value
GROUP BY t.pkid, t.catid, t.value
HAVING COUNT(b.value) + 1 <= 5
ORDER BY t.catid, t.value DESC, t.pkid
```

Make the following change to produce results similar to `DENSE_RANK` function:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT b.value)
```

Or make the following change to produce results similar to `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
ON b.catid = t.catid AND (b.value > t.value OR b.value = t.value AND b.pkid < t.pkid)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pylxnDj5)

Comment: +1 your answer rewrite is very valid, as modern MySQL/MariaDB versions follow the ANSI/ISO SQL 1992/1999/2003 standards more where it was never really was allowed to use `ORDER BY` in deliverd/subqueries like that.. That is the reason why modern MySQL/MariaDB versions ignore the `ORDER BY` in subquery without using `LIMIT`, i believe ANSI/ISO SQL Standards 2008/2011/2016 makes `ORDER BY` in deliverd/subqueries legal when using it in combination with `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`

Comment: Great, this works perfectly ... I came across another solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48593547) which uses a correlated subquery, that one also works and yields the same results, however I think your solution (with a join) runs a lot faster.

Answer (score 157):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregated function to get all years into a single column, grouped by `id` and ordered by `rate`:

```sql
SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(year ORDER BY rate DESC) grouped_year
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY id
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  ID | GROUPED_YEAR                                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| p01 | 2006,2003,2008,2001,2007,2009,2002,2004,2005,2000 |
| p02 | 2001,2004,2002,2003,2000,2006,2007                |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And then you could use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), that returns the position of the first argument inside the second one, eg.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2006', '2006,2003,2008,2001,2007,2009,2002,2004,2005,2000');
1

SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2009', '2006,2003,2008,2001,2007,2009,2002,2004,2005,2000');
6
```

Using a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `FIND_IN_SET`, and filtering by the position returned by find_in_set, you could then use this query that returns only the first 5 years for every id:

```
SELECT
  yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(year ORDER BY rate DESC) grouped_year
    FROM
      yourtable
    GROUP BY id) group_max
  ON yourtable.id = group_max.id
     AND FIND_IN_SET(year, grouped_year) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
ORDER BY
  yourtable.id, yourtable.year DESC;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c220/1).

Please note that if more than one row can have the same rate, you should consider using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rate ORDER BY rate)` on the `rate` column instead of the `year` column.

The maximum length of the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` is limited, so this works well if you need to select a few records for every group.

Comment: That's *beautifully* performant, comparatively simple, and great explanation; thank you SO MUCH. To your last point, Where a reasonable maximum length can be computed, one can use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = <maximum length>;` In the OP's case, a non-issue (since the default is 1024), but by way of example, group_concat_max_len should be at least 25: 4 (max length of a year string) + 1 (separator character), times 5 (first 5 years).  The strings are truncated rather than throwing an error, so watch for warnings such as `1054 rows in set, 789 warnings (0.31 sec)`.

Comment: If i want to fetch exact 2 rows rather than 1 to 5 than what should I use with `FIND_IN_SET()`. I tried for `FIND_IN_SET() =2` but not showing result as expected.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET BETWEEN 1 and 5 will take the first 5 positions of GROUP_CONCAT set if size equal to or greater than 5. So FIND_IN_SET = 2 will take only the data with the 2nd position in your GROUP_CONCAT. Getting 2 rows you can try BETWEEN 1 and 2 for 1st and 2nd position assuming set has 2 rows to give.

Comment: This solution has much better performance than Salman's for large datasets. I gave a thumbs up to both for such clever solutions anyway. Thanks!!

Comment: Regarding "this works well if you need to select a few records for every group": does MySQL actually _avoid reading more data_ once the string is full? I have a suspicion that it will first load all rows into memory, thus risking a full index/table scan regardless of the max string length. I'd be thrilled if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wow! Talk about MySql dark arts!  This solution is brilliant, lightning fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

For me something like

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(col_name order by desired_col_order_name), ',', N)
```

works perfectly. No complicated query.

---

for example: get top 1 for each group

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id
                            ORDER BY rate DESC),
                        ',',
                        1) id
        FROM
            yourtable
        GROUP BY year)
ORDER BY rate DESC;
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, but I also want to retrieve year and other columns from the subquery, How can we do that?

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT year, id, rate
FROM (SELECT
  year, id, rate, row_number() over (partition by id order by rate DESC)
  FROM h
  WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
  AND id IN (SELECT rid FROM table2)
  GROUP BY id, year
  ORDER BY id, rate DESC) as subquery
WHERE row_number <= 5
```

The subquery is almost identical to your query. Only change is adding

```
row_number() over (partition by id order by rate DESC)
```

Comment: This is nice but MySQL has no window functions (like `ROW_NUMBER()`).

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0, `row_number()` is [available](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number).

Comment: For the example to work as is, would only add an alias to the row number:  `(row_number() over (partition by user_id order by created_at DESC)) as row_number`

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't LIMIT subqueries arbitrarily (you can do it to a limited extent in newer MySQLs, but not for 5 results per group).

This is a groupwise-maximum type query, which is not trivial to do in SQL. There are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id/756892#756892) to tackle that which can be more efficient for some cases, but for top-n in general you'll want to look at [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867) to a similar previous question.

As with most solutions to this problem, it can return more than five rows if there are multiple rows with the same `rate` value, so you may still need a quantity of post-processing to check for that.

Answer (score 10):

This requires a series of subqueries to rank the values, limit them, then perform the sum while grouping

```
@Rnk:=0;
@N:=2;
select
  c.id,
  sum(c.val)
from (
select
  b.id,
  b.bal
from (
select   
  if(@last_id=id,@Rnk+1,1) as Rnk,
  a.id,
  a.val,
  @last_id=id,
from (   
select 
  id,
  val 
from list
order by id,val desc) as a) as b
where b.rnk < @N) as c
group by c.id;
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
SELECT h.year, h.id, h.rate 
FROM (SELECT h.year, h.id, h.rate, IF(@lastid = (@lastid:=h.id), @index:=@index+1, @index:=0) indx 
      FROM (SELECT h.year, h.id, h.rate 
            FROM h
            WHERE h.year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009 AND id IN (SELECT rid FROM table2)
            GROUP BY id, h.year
            ORDER BY id, rate DESC
            ) h, (SELECT @lastid:='', @index:=0) AS a
    ) h 
WHERE h.indx <= 5;
```

Comment: unknown column a.type in field list

Answer (score 6):

Build the virtual columns（like RowID in Oracle）

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `stack` 
(`year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`rate` float DEFAULT NULL) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**Data:**

```
insert into stack values(2006,'p01',8);
insert into stack values(2001,'p01',5.9);
insert into stack values(2007,'p01',5.3);
insert into stack values(2009,'p01',4.4);
insert into stack values(2001,'p02',12.5);
insert into stack values(2004,'p02',12.4);
insert into stack values(2005,'p01',2.1);
insert into stack values(2000,'p01',0.8);
insert into stack values(2002,'p02',12.2);
insert into stack values(2002,'p01',3.9);
insert into stack values(2004,'p01',3.5);
insert into stack values(2003,'p02',10.3);
insert into stack values(2000,'p02',8.7);
insert into stack values(2006,'p02',4.6);
insert into stack values(2007,'p02',3.3);
insert into stack values(2003,'p01',7.4);
insert into stack values(2008,'p01',6.8);
```

**SQL like this:**

```
select t3.year,t3.id,t3.rate 
from (select t1.*, (select count(*) from stack t2 where t1.rate<=t2.rate and t1.id=t2.id) as rownum from stack t1) t3 
where rownum <=3 order by id,rate DESC;
```

If delete the where clause in t3, it shows like this:

[image]

GET "TOP N Record" --> add the `rownum <=3` in `where` clause (the where-clause of t3);

CHOOSE "the year" --> add the `BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009` in `where` clause (the where-clause of t3);

Comment: If you have rates that repeat for the same id, then this will not work because  your rowNum count will increase higher; you will not get 3 per row, you can get 0, 1 or 2. Can you think of any solution to this?

Comment: @starvator change the "t1.rate<=t2.rate" to "t1.rate<t2.rate", if the best rate has same values in the same id, all of them has the same rownum but will not increase higher; like "rate 8 in id p01", if it repeats, by using "t1.rate<t2.rate", both of "rate 8 in id p01" has the same rownum 0; if using "t1.rate<=t2.rate", the rownum is 2;

Answer (score 3):

Took some working, but I thougth my solution would be something to share as it is seems elegant as well as quite fast.

```
SELECT h.year, h.id, h.rate 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(id, '-', year) ORDER BY rate DESC), ',' , 5) AS l
      FROM h
      WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009
      GROUP BY id
      ORDER BY id
  ) AS h_temp
    LEFT JOIN h ON h.id = h_temp.id 
      AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(h_temp.l, CONCAT(h.id, '-', h.year), 1) != h_temp.l
```

Note that this example is specified for the purpose of the question and can be modified quite easily for other similar purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The following post: [sql: selcting top N record per group](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group) describes the complicated way of achieving this without subqueries.

It improves on other solutions offered here by:

- Doing everything in a single query
- Being able to properly utilize indexes
- Avoiding subqueries, notoriously known to produce bad execution plans in MySQL

It is however not pretty. A good solution would be achievable were Window Functions (aka Analytic Functions) enabled in MySQL -- but they are not.
The trick used in said post utilizes GROUP_CONCAT, which is sometimes described as "poor man's Window Functions for MySQL".

Answer (score 1):

for those like me that had queries time out. I made the below to use limits and anything else by a specific group.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE count_limit200()
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT Default 0;
    DECLARE stop_loop INT Default 0;
    DECLARE domain_val VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE domain_list CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM db.one;

    OPEN domain_list;

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(domain)) INTO stop_loop 
    FROM db.one;
    -- BEGIN LOOP
    loop_thru_domains: LOOP
        FETCH domain_list INTO domain_val;
        SET a=a+1;

        INSERT INTO db.two(book,artist,title,title_count,last_updated) 
        SELECT * FROM 
        (
            SELECT book,artist,title,COUNT(ObjectKey) AS titleCount, NOW() 
            FROM db.one 
            WHERE book = domain_val
            GROUP BY artist,title
            ORDER BY book,titleCount DESC
            LIMIT 200
        ) a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title_count = titleCount, last_updated = NOW();

        IF a = stop_loop THEN
            LEAVE loop_thru_domain;
        END IF;
    END LOOP loop_thru_domain;
END $$
```

it loops through a list of domains and then inserts only a limit of 200 each

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @num := 0, @type := '';
SELECT `year`, `id`, `rate`,
    @num := if(@type = `id`, @num + 1, 1) AS `row_number`,
    @type := `id` AS `dummy`
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `h`
    WHERE (
        `year` BETWEEN '2000' AND '2009'
        AND `id` IN (SELECT `rid` FROM `table2`) AS `temp_rid`
    )
    ORDER BY `id`
) AS `temph`
GROUP BY `year`, `id`, `rate`
HAVING `row_number`<='5'
ORDER BY `id`, `rate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below stored procedure. I have already verified. I am getting proper result but without using `groupby`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ks_root`@`%` PROCEDURE `first_five_record_per_id`()
BEGIN
DECLARE query_string text;
DECLARE datasource1 varchar(24);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tenants varchar(50);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT rid FROM demo1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    SET @query_string='';

      OPEN cur1;
      read_loop: LOOP

      FETCH cur1 INTO tenants ;

      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      SET @datasource1 = tenants;
      SET @query_string = concat(@query_string,'(select * from demo  where `id` = ''',@datasource1,''' order by rate desc LIMIT 5) UNION ALL ');

       END LOOP; 
      close cur1;

    SET @query_string  = TRIM(TRAILING 'UNION ALL' FROM TRIM(@query_string));  
  select @query_string;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query_string;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a top operation for MYSQL. The code is straightforward.

```
drop table if exists h;
create table h(id varchar(5), year int, rate numeric(8,2), primary key(id,year));
insert into h(year, id, rate) values
(2006,'p01',8),
(2003,'p01',7.4),
(2008,'p01',6.8),
(2001,'p01',5.9),
(2007,'p01',5.3),
(2009,'p01',4.4),
(2002,'p01',3.9),
(2004,'p01',3.5),
(2005,'p01',2.1),
(2000,'p01',0.8),
(2001,'p02',12.5),
(2004,'p02',12.4),
(2002,'p02',12.2),
(2003,'p02',10.3),
(2000,'p02',8.7),
(2006,'p02',4.6),
(2007,'p02',3.3);

select id, year, rate
from 
(
    select id, year, rate, @last, if(@last=id,@top:=@top+1, @top:=0) as ztop, @last:=id update_last
    from h
    order by id, rate desc, year desc
) t2
where ztop<5
```

Comment: Have you check the execution plan with regards to the inner query? Won't MySQL scan _the entire table_ to satisfy the inner query, before taking the measly top 5 items? It sounds like a performance booby trap.

Comment: @Timo It's as bad as the top answer.