# MySQL : select 10 rows per day with order and on certain group

Tags: mysql

I have MySql database with lots of records with date (timestamp) and few more attributes.
As an example 'testTable' looks like

a   varchar(255)    
 b   int( 11)  
  timestamp  bigint(20)

I need to find top 10 of sum(b) for each day for a period of time say Jan 1st to Jan 15th where those dates can be specified by user.

How will the iterative query look like ?
Crude way could be individual select statements  with UNION ALL in between.

```
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) between '2012-01-01 05:10:00' and '2012-01-02 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) between '2012-01-02 05:10:00' and '2012-01-03 05:10:00' group by a  order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) between '2012-01-03 05:10:00' and '2012-01-04 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
..
..
..
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( timestamp ) between '2012-01-14 05:10:00' and '2012-01-15 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10 ;</br>
```

But I want it to be more generic where user can run a script with 2 given dates.

output is like 

a          |      FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)    | sum  (b)

-----------+------------------------+------

 test  | 2012-01-01 03:24:41-04 |  500

 test  | 2012-01-01 03:19:40-04 |  420

 test  | 2012-01-01 03:14:39-04 |  261 

 test  | 2012-01-01 03:09:38-04 |  244 

 test  | 2012-01-01 03:04:37-04 |  231

 test  | 2012-01-01 02:59:36-04 |  223 

 test  | 2012-01-01 02:54:35-04 |  211 

 test1 | 2012-01-01 02:49:34-04 |  199 

 test1 | 2012-01-01 03:24:41-04 |  195 

 test1 | 2012-01-01 03:19:40-04 |  191 

 new   | 2012-01-02 06:11:06-04 | 1000

 new   | 2012-01-02 06:06:06-04 | 978

 new   | 2012-01-02 06:01:06-04 | 867

 new   | 2012-01-02 05:56:05-04 | 786 

new   | 2012-01-02 05:51:05-04 | 698

 new   | 2012-01-02 05:46:05-04 | 598

 new1  | 2012-01-02 06:11:06-04 | 476

 new1  | 2012-01-02 05:41:04-04 | 345

 new2  | 2012-01-02 06:06:06-04 |  250

 new2  | 2012-01-02 06:01:06-04 |  125

Comment: select a, sum(b)  from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( a ) between '2012-01-01 05:10:00' and '2012-01-02 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( a ) between '2012-01-03 05:10:00' and '2012-01-04 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
..
..
..
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where FROM_UNIXTIME( a ) between '2012-01-14 05:10:00' and '2012-01-15 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10 ;

Comment: Realized that after adding the comments. I have updated the query.Thanks

Comment: What does the timestamp refer to in that sample resultset, since you're grouping on `a`? Timestamps are typically for individual rows and wouldn't be the same within a whole group.

Comment: timestamp is stored as bigint in database upto the seconds granularity

Comment: Your question with the union portions and your output don't match up. I posted an answer based on your previous revision of this question.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, [SQL statements](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use complete `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. Until SO supports [`<samp>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42692/133817), sample output is best marked up with `<blockquote><pre>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql limit inside group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1153738/), [How do I select multiple items from each group in a mysql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1304599/), and ***MANY*** [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) (and [yet more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+%2Btop+%2Bn+%2Bgroup&submit=search)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this... Change the dates in the between range to pass the range only once.

**Corrected** for typo, omitted line, and missing comma:

```
select day, a, tot
from 
   (
   select 
      *,
      @num := if(@day =  tt4.day, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @day := tt4.day as dummy
   from
      (
      select
         ts as day, 
         tt1.a, 
         sum(tt1.b) as tot
      from 
         testTable tt1, 
         ( select distinct date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tt2.timestamp)) as ts
           from   testTable tt2
           where  date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tt2.timestamp)) between cast('2012/01/01' as date) and cast('2012/01/15' as date) ) as tt3
      where 
         date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tt1.timestamp)) = tt3.ts
      group by 
         date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tt1.timestamp)), 
         tt1.a
      order by 
         date(FROM_UNIXTIME(tt1.timestamp)),
         sum(tt1.b) desc,
         tt1.a
      ) as tt4
   ) as tt5
where 
   tt5.row_number <=10
```

**Modified** - flavor of SQL changed for Vertica... syntax may be off (I don't have a Vertica installation to test against), but the gist is there.

```
select day, a, tot
from 
   (
   select 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt4.day) as row_number
   from
      (
      select
         ts as day, 
         tt1.a, 
         sum(tt1.b) as tot
      from 
         testTable tt1, 
         ( select distinct date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt2.timestamp)) as ts
           from   testTable tt2
           where  date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt2.timestamp)) between cast('2012/01/01' as date) and cast('2012/01/15' as date) ) as tt3
      where 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)) = tt3.ts
      group by 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)), 
         tt1.a
      order by 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)),
         sum(tt1.b) desc,
         tt1.a
      ) as tt4
   ) as tt5
where 
   tt5.row_number <=10
```

Comment: This is a variation of the Top N Per Group scenario posted elsewhere... Check out http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ for more details.

Comment: Tony, I have all sorts of errors when I try to execute the query that you have.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an interim iteration I was working with.  I corrected the code above.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Any idea to convert this to Vertica vSQL ? Looks like the variable declaration is  different in vSQL.

Comment: Sorry, no... you said MySQL in the question. Is there an online reference for vSQL syntax? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Looks like Vertica supports row_count()... that makes it pretty easy.  Change the variable declarations to "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt4.day) as row_number"

Comment: Did my revision for Vertica syntax help you?