# Vertica/vSQL " select 10 rows per day with order and on certain group

Tags: vertica

I have Vertica database with lots of records with date (timestamp) and few more attributes. As an example 'testTable' looks like

```
a varchar(255)
b int
timestamp bigint
```

I need to find top 10 of `sum(b)` for each day for a period of time (say Jan 1st to Jan 15th) where those dates can be specified by user.

How will the iterative query look like? Crude way could be individual `SELECT` statements with `UNION ALL` in between.

```
select a, sum(b) from testTable where TO_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) between '2012-01-01 05:10:00' and '2012-01-02 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where TO_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) between '2012-01-02 05:10:00' and '2012-01-03 05:10:00' group by a  order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where TO_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) between '2012-01-03 05:10:00' and '2012-01-04 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10
..
..
..
UNION ALL
select a, sum(b) from testTable where TO_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) between '2012-01-14 05:10:00' and '2012-01-15 05:10:00' group by a order by sum(b) desc LIMIT 10 ;
```

But I want it to be more generic where the user can run a script with two given dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL : select 10 rows per day with order and on certain group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506894/mysql-select-10-rows-per-day-with-order-and-on-certain-group)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to convert that same query to vSQL syntax. Vertica declaration of variables seem to be different

Answer (score 0):

Syntax might be off a bit...I don't have Vertica to test against.

```
select day, a, tot
from 
   (
   select 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt4.day) as row_number
   from
      (
      select
         ts as day, 
         tt1.a, 
         sum(tt1.b) as tot
      from 
         testTable tt1, 
         ( select distinct date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt2.timestamp)) as ts
           from   testTable tt2
           where  date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt2.timestamp)) between cast('2012/01/01' as date) and cast('2012/01/15' as date) ) as tt3
      where 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)) = tt3.ts
      group by 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)), 
         tt1.a
      order by 
         date(TO_TIMESTAMP(tt1.timestamp)),
         sum(tt1.b) desc,
         tt1.a
      ) as tt4
   ) as tt5
where 
   tt5.row_number <=10
```